# Can't call PHP's date() inside a class?

Tags: php

I get an error when I use date() when initializing an instance variable

```
class User extends Connectable {
    private $date = date('Y-m-d');
}
```

The error is

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
```

This is weird, because it works fine when I call date() from inside a function, or outside the class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a **constant value**, that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

You could initialize it in the constructor method.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I needed. Is there any more documentation on this topic?

Comment: php.net holds all the informations you need. http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.constructor.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Wait, since when was PHP compiled? Isn't it an interpreted language?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton Yes, php is interpreted, here the `compile time` is the opposite to the `run time`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that under a `constructor`

```
<?php
class User extends Connectable {
    private $date;
    function __construct()
    {
    $this->date = date('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Such expressions are not allowed as a field default value. You need to set them in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

try this you can use a constructor for it which initialize your private variable when the object is created.

```
class User extends Connectable {
    private $date1; 

    function __construct()
     {
       $this->date1 = date('Y-m-d');
     }
}
```